# Retrieve serial port information of a libvirt domain?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I'm trying to retrieve the serial port information, aka `Source Path` of a libvirt domain (using qemu/KVM machine):

```
Serial Device 1 (Primary Console)
  Device type: pty
  Source path: /dev/pts/2
```

But I checked the [API reference here](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html) and it doesn't seem to support a `Source Path`.

Is there any command like `VBoxManage` that can list such information directly?

---

Weird, I'm in the `libvirt` group, I can control (start, stop etc.) the KVM machine with `virt-manager`, `virsh` also shows a `virsh #` prompt.

But I'm not able to see anything with `virsh list --all` command, I still have to run that with root privileges.

Comment: Sounds like your question has more to do with libvirt than with qemu (the one emulating the serial port), let alone kvm which has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `virsh dumpxml domain | xmlstarlet sel -t -c //serial`?

Comment: Or: `virsh dumpxml domain | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//serial[target/@port=0]/source/@path'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I started a KVM machine from virt-manager, but `virsh list --all` shows nothing, am I wrong?

Comment: you should use http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainOpenConsole and not get the device name directly

Comment: @warl0ck - was that a `sudo virsh list --all`? Reg. users can't see the output of `virsh`, typically.

Comment: @slm Yes with sudo it worked. The prompt from virsh is pretty confusing, it shows a `virsh #` even for non-privileged user. But I'm already in `libvirt` group, the virsh list command should work (I can start virt-manager and control those KVM without sudo)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas where is that `xmlstartlet` command, or what package it belongs to ..? I couldn't find it ;-( not in libxml2 at least

Comment: @warl0ck - yes you should be able to control them via `virt-manager` since that's talking to the libvirtd daemon, w/o sudo.

Comment: @slm I got it, root user reads `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`, but normal user reads a different sock located in `/run/`. Problem solved.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Please put your comments as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

KVM is a kernel API for virtualisation. It doesn't deal with *serial ports*. `qemu` is a machine (PC and other) emulator which can use `kvm` for improving virtualisation performance. It can emulate a standard 8250 UART serial port (`isa-serial`) or paravirtualised serial port (`virtio-serial`).

In qemu, you define your machine with command-line arguments that specify what device to add to your machine and what *backend* those devices map to (for instance emulated hard disk to an image file, network adapters to a `tap` device...).

For serial ports, you typically map that to what qemu calls *chardevs*.

There is a lot of possible different ones, typically anything that can send and receive bytes, like pipes, sockets, file descriptors, pseudo-terminals.

For instance if you run qemu as:

```
qemu ... -device isa-serial,chardev=c,id=s -chardev pty,id=c
```

qemu allocates a pseudo-terminal, reports that on stdout on startup:

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/18 (label c)
```

and maps that to a new *isa* serial port added to the VM. If booting a Linux VM, you'll see in its kernel logs:

```
[    3.636092] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    3.658666] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

And if you write something to `/dev/ttyS0` in the guest, you'll be able to read it on `/dev/pts/18` on the host.

After a qemu VM is started, you can control it with what qemu calls *monitor* interfaces. There are two types of *monitor* interfaces:

- Human monitor: a shell-like CLI
- Machine monitor: a more machine friendly interface implementing a text (json) protocol called qemu machine protocol (QMP).

If you don't specify anything and use the default SDL console, you get a *human monitor* in the SDL console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+2</kbd>.

But you can also specify any *chardev* backend (pty, socket, stdio...) for that. Typically, I use `stdio` there:

```
qemu ... -monitor stdio
```

To get the *monitor* on the terminal I start qemu from when running qemu for tests.

In that *monitor* interface, you can run the `info qtree` command to get information about the devices of your machine:

```
(qemu) info qtree
bus: main-system-bus
[...]
  dev: i440FX-pcihost, id ""
[...]
bus: pci.0
[...]
  dev: PIIX3, id ""
    class ISA bridge, addr 00:01.0, pci id 8086:7000 (sub 1af4:1100)
    bus: isa.0
      type ISA
      dev: isa-serial, id "s"
    index = 0 (0)
    iobase = 1016 (0x3f8)
    irq = 4 (0x4)
    chardev = "c"
```

Above, you see the `isa-serial` device I created earlier and that it maps to the `"c"` *chardev*.

You can get information from that chardev using `info chardev`:

```
(qemu) info chardev
parallel0: filename=vc
c: filename=pty:/dev/pts/18
compat_monitor0: filename=stdio
```

You see `c` maps to the `/dev/pts/18` *pty*.

You can get the same information programmatically with a QMP monitor. If you start your VM with `-qmp stdio`, you can pass the commands there:

```
{"execute":"qmp_capabilities"} # enable commands
{"return": {}}   # return value

{"execute":"qom-list","arguments":{"path":"/machine/peripheral/s"}}
{"return": [{"name": "parent_bus", "type": "link<bus>"}, {"name": "wakeup", "type": "uint32"}, {"name": "chardev", "type": "str"}, {"name": "irq", "type": "uint32"}, {"name": "iobase", "type": "uint32"}, {"name": "index", "type": "uint32"}, {"name": "hotpluggable", "type": "bool"}, {"name": "realized", "type": "bool"}, {"name": "type", "type": "string"}]}

# query chardev for "s":
{"execute":"qom-get","arguments":{"path":"/machine/peripheral/s","property":"chardev"}}
{"return": "c"}

# query chardevs:
{"execute":"query-chardev"}
{"return": [{"filename": "vc", "label": "parallel0"}, {"filename": "pty:/dev/pts/18", "label": "c"}, {"filename": "stdio", "label": "compat_monitor0"}]}
```

(see how those `qom-list` and `qom-get` (qom standing for qemu object model) are reminiscent of doing `ls` and `cat` in `/sys` on Linux machine).

Now your question suggests that you're not calling qemu directly by hand but instead using `libvirt`. `libvirt` is one of many virtualisation management infrastructures. It can manage qemu (with or without kvm), xen or virtualbox (at least) VMs.

For qemu VMs, when you define a VM in libvirt (with virt-manager or other), that will translate to arguments to be passed to a qemu command, and libvirt will  typically use a qmp monitor to control a VM after it's been started.

For a `libvirt` domain, you can get the current configuration of a domain with:

```
virsh dumpxml the-domain
```

Which dumps the config as XML. You can extract information from that using `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` or any XML parsing solution of your choosing.

```
$ virsh dumpxml domain | xmllint --xpath '//serial' -
<serial type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/4"/>
  <target port="0"/>
  <alias name="serial0"/>
</serial><serial type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/5"/>
  <target port="1"/>
  <alias name="serial1"/>
</serial><serial type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/6"/>
  <target port="2"/>
  <alias name="serial2"/>
</serial>
$ virsh dumpxml domain |
  xmllint --xpath 'string(//serial[target/@port=0]/source/@path)' -
/dev/pts/4
```

The equivalent ones with `xmlstarlet`:

```
sudo virsh dumpxml domain | xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//serial'
sudo virsh dumpxml domain |
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//serial[target/@port=0]/source/@path'
```

Note that you can also pass commands to the QMP monitor with the `virsh qemu-monitor-command` command.

For instance:

```
$ virsh qemu-monitor-command domain '{"execute":"qom-get","arguments":
{"path":"/machine/peripheral/serial0","property":"chardev"}}'
{"return":"charserial0","id":"libvirt-84"}
```